# Populate bootstrap modal from gridview edit link button

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview containing membership providers roles.
[image]

With Link Button For editing and Link button for deleting.

I want to populate a modal with a text box inside it to save the role name as shown.
[image]

I succeeded in populating the modal and binding the grid and all of that, but, how can I bind the `txtRoleName` in the modal with the role name of the row? Preferably without any postback if possible, or with postback if not.

Here is the code for the grid:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdRoles"
            CssClass="table table-bordered responsive"
            runat="server"
            GridLines="None"
            CellSpacing="-1" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            OnPageIndexChanging="grdRoles_PageIndexChanging"
            OnRowDataBound="grdRoles_RowDataBound"
            ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="Empty !">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roles">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRoleName" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton  ID="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal"  href="#EditModal" runat="server" CssClass="btn  icon-edit" />
                    <asp:LinkButton  ID="btnRemove" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger remove"  Text="<i class=icon-remove></i>" />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the code for the modal:

```
 <div id="EditModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Edit"
         aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     <h3 id="helpModalLabel"><i class="icon-external-link"></i> Edit Role</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="control-group">
       <div class="controls">
         <div class="input-prepend">
           <span class="add-on">Role Name</span>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtRoleName" Text='<%# Bind("RoleId") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-actions">
         <asp:Button ID="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Save" />
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using data property to send data to the modal:

```
<a id="edit" href="#dlgName" data-toggle="modal" role="button" 
   data-id="<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Id") %>" 
   data-IsPrimary ="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsPrimary") %>" >Edit</a>
```

And, retrieve the data  using jQuery:

```
var Id = $('#edit').data('Id');
var isprimary = $('#edit').data('IsPrimary');
```

Comment: this is a great answer, but I need to add this: when you use "data-XxxYyy", in jquery you need to retrieve the data using all lowercase: var Id = $('#edit').data('xxxyyy'); JQuery converts these to lowercase upon render